# need help creating a simple many-to-many relationship using mysql

Tags: mysql, database

So I got used to using doctrine so much that I forgot the standard mysql syntax, which I need for an exam.

I want to create a test database called 'youtube'
with an `app_users` table and an `app_videos` table.

In "real life" this would be a oneToMany relationship, but I need to 
study to create a manyToMany relationship.

so its 
"many app_users" -> have "many app_videos"
and the other way around.

so first I created a database;

```
CREATE DATABASE youtube;
use youtube;
```

then I created the users and videos table

```
CREATE TABLE app_users(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(20),
    password VARCHAR(40),
    first_name VARCHAR(20),
    last_name VARCHAR(20),
    video_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE app_videos(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    video_path VARCHAR(20),
    description VARCHAR(20),
    likes INT(20),
    dislikes INT(20),
    user_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

then I created a relationship table

```
CREATE TABLE vid_uid 
(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    video_id INT,
    user_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

now what I need to do is somehow connect the columns to eachother but my syntax never works

[image: realationship]

I know I need to change this

```
ALTER TABLE app_users
ADD FOREIGN KEY(video_id)
REFERENCES app_videos(video_id);
```

to something that works :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change app_videos(video_id) to app_videos(id). Also you want to alter the table vid_uid (not app_users) since thats the one that as references to external keys:

```
ALTER TABLE vid_uid
ADD FOREIGN KEY(video_id)
REFERENCES app_videos(id);
```

You'll also need to do:

```
ALTER TABLE vid_uid
ADD FOREIGN KEY(user_id)
REFERENCES app_users(id);
```